# Tablero de ajedrez python con listas

Tags: python, lista

Me pidieron lo siguiente:Utilizando listas, crear un programa que genere tableros de ajedrez aleatorios
a)un tablero de ajedrez debe tener en cada equipo (blancas y negras):
Entre 0 y 8 Peones
Entre 0 y 2 Caballos
Entre 0 y 2 Alfiles
Entre 0 y 2 Torres
Entre 0 y 1 Reina
1 Rey
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hago el tablero con piezas alazares pero no puedo cumplir con la consigna del rango de piezas

```
from random import sample
linea1=[];linea2=[];linea3=[];linea4=[];linea5=[];linea6=[];linea7=[];linea8=[]
lista=['cN','cB','aN','aB','tN','tB','raN','raB','ryN','ryB','  ']
for i in range(8):
    linea1=sample(lista,k=8)
    linea2=sample(lista,k=8)
    linea3=sample(lista,k=8)
    linea4=sample(lista,k=8)
    linea5=sample(lista,k=8)
    linea6=sample(lista,k=8)
    linea7=sample(lista,k=8)
    linea8=sample(lista,k=8)
    print(linea1)
    print(linea2)
    print(linea3)
    print(linea4)
    print(linea5)
    print(linea6)
    print(linea7)
    print(linea8)
    break
```

Mi problema es que no puedo cumplir con el rango de cantidades de piezas

Comment: Bienvenido Juan a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas..

Comment: Publica lo que has hecho hasta el momento y cual es el punto donde estás trabado.

Comment: @CandidMoe Ahí publiqué lo que he hecho hasta el momento

Comment: Cada vez que puebles una lineaX, examinala para ver que piezas incluiste. Luego saca esas piezas de "lista" y procesa la siguiente líneaX. Eso hará que las piezas no se utilicen múltiples veces. Haz eso, y edita tu pregunta para ver como vas avanzando a la solución.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esta es un método posible:

1. Crear una lista "piezas" con las 32 piezas.
2. Crear una lista "tablero" con 64 casillas, inicialmente pobladas con "__" para señalar una casilla vacia.
3. Extraer una muestra de "piezas" y recorrerla extrayendo una pieza a la vez.
4. Ubicar una casilla vacía al azar y poner la pieza ahi.

from random import randint, sample

```
    piezas = ["Kw", "Qw", "Rw", "Rw", "Bw", "Bw",
              "Nw", "Nw", "Pw", "Pw", "Pw", "Pw",
              "Pw", "Pw", "Pw", "Pw",
              "Kb", "Qb", "Rb", "Rb", "Bb", "Bb",
              "Nb", "Nb", "Pb", "Pb", "Pb", "Pb",
              "Pb", "Pb", "Pb", "Pb"]
    tablero = ["__" for x in range(64)]
    
    # Generar una seleccion de piezas al azar.
    max = randint(1, len(piezas))
    seleccion = sample(piezas, max)

    for pieza in seleccion:
        # Tomamos una pieza
        while True:
           # Buscamos al azar una casilla vacia
           indice = randint(0, len(tablero) - 1)
           if tablero[indice] == "__":
               # Encontramos una casilla vacia; poblarla y salir
               tablero[indice] = pieza
               break

    # Impresion
    for fila in range(8):
        for columna in range(8):
            print(tablero[fila * 8 + columna], end = " ")
        print()
```

Produce:

```
__ Bw Bw __ __ __ __ __ 
__ __ __ __ __ __ __ __ 
__ Rw __ __ __ __ __ __ 
__ __ __ __ __ __ __ __ 
Qw __ __ Pw __ __ __ __ 
__ Nw __ __ Rw __ __ __ 
__ __ Nw __ __ __ __ Pw 
__ __ Kw __ __ __ __ __
```

**Observaciones**

Tablero es una simple lista uni-dimensional. Los primeros ocho elementos corresponden a la primera fila; los siguientes ocho, a la segunda fila y asi sucesivamente.

Elegi esta representación por que resulta más cómodo que trabajar con un arreglo bi-dimensional. Para convertir de `arreglo[fila][columna]` a la `lista[indice]` (uni-dimensional) se emplea la formula `indice=fila*8 + columna`.

Elegi usar "__" para representar una casilla vacía para que el resultado impreso quede alineado correctamente.

La notación de las piezas sigue las convenciones internacionales corrientes.

Answer (score -1):

Ahora bien, sí te piden calcular el puntaje de ambos jugadores tomando en cuenta un valor que se le da a cada pieza.
Cómo sería?
Ejemplo:
Peón: 1
Alfil:4
Torre:5
Caballo:4
Rey:4
Reina:9
Sí pudieras explicarlo te lo agradecería.
Basándonos en la explicación anterior.

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Si tienes una nueva pregunta, la puedes formular haciendo clic en el botón [Formular una pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). Incluye un enlace a esta pregunta si ayuda a proporcionar contexto. - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/362922)